# how to run any file and how to write to file - in C# - Visual studio 2003?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

i have to work on old project that written on Visual-Studio 2003 (windows-mobile 5.0)

and i dont know how to do this:

1. how to run any file from the program (for example need to run prog2.exe)
2. how to write to MyText.txt the word "TEST"

thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

For the first, use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

For the second, in the Compact Framework you'd need:

```
using (TextWriter writer = new TextWriter("test.txt"))
{
    writer.Write("TEST");
}
```

I believe `Process.Start` should be okay in Windows Mobile though...

If you can upgrade to a later version of the Compact Framework, you could use `File.WriteAllText`.

Comment: @Beatles1692: I *think* so... it looks like it based on MSDN.